# Grouping by one column and two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the following table, I need to find out the login date and how long a user's session spanned.  For example, empid=1 logged in (typeid=1) on 1/1/2009 @ 3:20 and logged off (typeid=2) the same day at 3:25.  The output should be:

```
logged on,      session length,  sessionid
1/1/2009 3:20   5:00             014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30D
```

Each sessionid is unique. How do I create such a query?

```
create table a (empid int, typeid int, created datetime, sessionid nvarchar(36))

insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(1, 1, '01/01/2009 3:20:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30D')
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(1, 2, '01/01/2009 3:25:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30D')
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(2, 1, '01/09/2009 4:20:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30E')
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(3, 1, '01/10/2009 3:25:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30F')
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(2, 2, '01/09/2009 4:23:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30E')
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(3, 2, '01/10/2009 4:25:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30F')
select * from a

drop table a
```

-- EDIT --
There are some scenarios I'd like to filter out.  As an example, for empid=1, it could be this instead:

```
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(1, 1, '01/01/2009 3:20:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30D')
insert into a(empid, typeid, created, sessionid) 
values(1, 1, '01/01/2009 3:25:00', '014A3B2C-3874-4D84-A5B3-F234AA2AE30D')
```

The above empid doesn't have a matching typeid=2.  There are two typeid=1.

Comment: You will have to do a self-join on session ID.

Comment: @DavidFaber - Not necessary at all, a simple `GROUP BY SessionId`  will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select empid,sessionid,
    min(created),max(created),
    datediff(mi,min(created),max(created)) 
from a 
group by empid,sessionid
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've added an edit for a scenario that maybe you can see how to filter out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LogOn.[created] as [logged on], DATEDIFF(day,LogOn.[created],LogOff.[created]) + ' ' + DATEDIFF(hour,LogOn.[created],LogOff.[created]) + ':' + DATEDIFF(minutes,LogOn.[created],LogOff.[created]) + ':' + DATEDIFF(second,LogOn.[created],LogOff.[created]), a.[sessionid] 
FROM a as [LogOn] 
JOIN a as [LogOff] ON LogOn.[sessionid] = LogOff.[sessionid] 
WHERE LogOn.[typeid] = 1 AND LogOff.[typeid] = 2
```

Comment: I suggest creating a unique index/constraint on sessionid,typeid.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  SessionId,
        MIN(CASE WHEN typeid = 1 THEN created END) [logged on],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND,MIN(CASE WHEN typeid = 1 THEN created END),MIN(CASE WHEN typeid = 2 THEN created END)) [session length]
FROM a
GROUP BY sessionId
```

You will need to manipulate the session length to obtain the desired output format, though.